# When apps comes in foreground, popup window screen is not working inside WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, appdelegate

I have used `WKWebView`for a loading a website let's (www.example.com) this website has JavaScript function of

```
window.open('some_valid_url')
```

I've managed to open window in webview by

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures)
```

By doing so, the window is opened normally in `webView`. But the issue I faced is, when I take my app to background and then back to foreground I'm not able to open windows.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for 
navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
            print("url is \(String(describing: webView.url))")
            popupWebView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: configuration)
            popupWebView!.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
            popupWebView!.navigationDelegate = self
            popupWebView!.uiDelegate = self
            view.addSubview(popupWebView!)
            return popupWebView!

        }
```

Note: I have added a debug point inside the above method after coming from background, the debug point is executed and new window is also opened but the window which is opened has URL of about:blank rather than the URL to be opened.

Comment: Are you sure you’re initializing your WebView properly? Also idk if that helps but you can also exec JS in webViews right? Maybe you can use that as workaround? .-.

Comment: @thisIsTheFoxe   I have initialize popwebview as follows var popupWebView: WKWebView? and also declare java script property preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true